# sending multiple email failed php mail

Tags: php, html, email

I want to send the email to two emails in one time, the first one to `office@example.com` the second one to guest who fill the form. 
Here my code

```
$email_to = "$c[email]"; 
$email_toko="office@example.com";
$subjek="**The Bandha Hotel** – Request for Pricing Submitted";

$dari = "From: {$email_toko}\r\n"
      . "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
      . "Reply-To: {$email_to}\r\n"
      . "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"
      . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to,$subjek,$pesan,$dari);
mail($email_toko,$subjek,$pesan,$dari);
```

but the email just send to `$email_toko` or just go to `office@example.com`. So the guest doesn't receive the email.help me please

Comment: Have you tried something like $email_to='email@example.org,email1@example.org'

Comment: What exactly is `$c[email]` supposed to be? Turn on errorlogging and you will see that it's probably undefined.

Comment: `"$c[email]"` will _not_ contain what you probably expect. Have a try using `$c['email']` instead (without the outer, but with additional inner quotes).

Comment: $c[email] from table of my database, although I try change $email_to="guest@example.com" still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that you can add Multiple recipients in [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) as below.

```
// Multiple recipients
$to = 'johny@example.com, sally@example.com'; // note the comma
```

In your code you are sending email separately to both of your address. `mail()`  function returns `Boolean` if mail send or fail so you can check the by dumping response of your mail function as below.

```
$mailRes = mail($email_to,$subjek,$pesan,$dari);
var_dump($mailRes);
```

Also enable [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) during development mode its helpful.

Comment: I try 
$email=$c['email'];
$email_to = '$email, wildanisa72@gmail.com';
$mailRes = mail($email_to,$subjek,$pesan,$dari);
    var_dump($mailRes);

but still can't send to $email

Comment: What did you get in dump response ? did you enable error reporting ?

Comment: I did 
error_reporting(0);

Comment: Check my given link in answer to enable error reporting first.

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: already solved, thanks